# How can I limit string length in android?

Tags: android

suppose I have a string below.

"This is my string blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"

I only want to show "This is my string" part and cut "blah" part.

So... I want to make my String as "This is my string" and do not want to

show my string as "this is my string blah blah blah blah".

Is there anyway to cut or limit String value in android?

Comment: What's  the criteria for the split?

Comment: well.. I only want to show first 50 characters. Basically, what I want is same as char[50]. I am googling now and looks like I can limit length of textview but I am looking for limiting string length.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Substring the string to 50 characters, which returns first 50 characters

You may need to something like this:

```
 String s = blahString.substring(0,50);
```

Then set those to your textbox:

```
yourText.setText(s);
```

Comment: If string is shorter than 50 chars - it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
Use this:
`String s = blahString.substring(0, Math.min(99, blahString.length() - 1));`

Comment: Is white space included?

Comment: This will crash and should be deleted.

Answer (score 10):

You could use ellipsize for TextViews for truncating the text if they are longer than the view. In that case, you don't need to hard code the 50 character limit.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize

Answer (score 7):

The answer marked as correct is poor and should not be used. If the supplied string is less than the substring range, then the code will crash. Check that the string exceeds the length you want to shorten to first.

```
public static String truncate(String str, int len) {
if (str.length() > len) {
  return str.substring(0, len) + "...";
} else {
  return str;
}}
```

Comment: More specifically it would raise IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: change return str.substring(0, len) + "..."; --> return str.substring(0, len - 3) + "..."; because it adds "..."(3 char) to the end.